# How to compare multiple rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to compare two consecutive rows `i` with `i-1` of `col2` (sorted by `col1`).

If `item_i` of the `i`-th row and the `item_[i-1]_row` are different, I'd like to increment the count of `item_[i-1]` by 1.

```
+--------------+
| col1 col2    |
+--------------+
| row_1 item_1 |
| row_2 item_1 |
| row_3 item_2 |
| row_4 item_1 |
| row_5 item_2 |
| row_6 item_1 |
+--------------+
```

In the above example, if we scan two rows at a time downwards, we see that `row_2` and `row_3` are different therefore we add one to item_1. Next, we see that `row_3` is different from `row_4`, then add one to `item_2`. Continue until we end up with:

```
+-------------+
|  col2  col3 |
+-------------+
|  item_1  2  |
|  item_2  2  |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a combination of a window function and an aggregate to do this. The window function is used to get the next value of `col2` (using `col1` for ordering). The aggregate then counts the times we encounter a differences. This is implemented in the code below:

```
val data = Seq(
  ("row_1", "item_1"),
  ("row_2", "item_1"),
  ("row_3", "item_2"),
  ("row_4", "item_1"),
  ("row_5", "item_2"),
  ("row_6", "item_1")).toDF("col1", "col2")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val q = data.
  withColumn("col2_next",
    coalesce(lead($"col2", 1) over Window.orderBy($"col1"), $"col2")).
  groupBy($"col2").
  agg(sum($"col2" =!= $"col2_next" cast "int") as "col3")

scala> q.show
17/08/22 10:15:53 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+------+----+
|  col2|col3|
+------+----+
|item_1|   2|
|item_2|   2|
+------+----+
```