# Filtering rows based on subsequent row values in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to filter out rows based on subsequent row values. Here is the sample dataframe

inputFrame

```
| id|value|sorted|
+---+-----+------+
|  3|    0|     6|
|  3|    1|     5|
|  3|    0|     7|
|  4|    1|     4|
|  4|    0|     1|
|  4|    0|     3|
+---+-----+------+
```

**Need to sort the DF based on sorted column**

```
scala> val sorted=origin.sort($"sorted".asc).show
  +---+-----+------+
            | id|value|sorted|
            +---+-----+------+
            |  4|    0|     1|
            |  4|    0|     3|
            |  4|    1|     4|
            |  3|    1|     5|
            |  3|    0|     6|
            |  3|    0|     7|
            +---+-----+------+
            ---+------+
```

**From the sorted frame, I have to create a data frame like below**

```
           id value sorted
            4   0      1
            4   0      3
            4   1      4
            3   1      5
```

Need to remove all the rows after 1(value) for each id.

I got the solution without the sort transformation from here([Filtering rows based on column values in spark dataframe scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374989/filtering-rows-based-on-column-values-in-spark-dataframe-scala)

I am really looking for a solution in Scala with sorted transformation.Thanks

Updated the solution here- [Filtering rows based on column values in spark dataframe scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374989/filtering-rows-based-on-column-values-in-spark-dataframe-scala)

Comment: Did you happen to try out something ? Or you just want others to code your homework for you ?

Comment: You should show a better example!

Comment: @eliasah I am bit new to spark.I tried with window functions , but I couldn't  find a solution for that. Still I am trying with that.. thanks

Comment: You already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374989/filtering-rows-based-on-column-values-in-spark-dataframe-scala/36377734#comment60374058_36377734

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul , yes but when I am using sorting transformation the solution  is not working as expected.monotonically_increasing_id() is generated based on original DF rather than sorted DF. I have missed  sorted transformation in my previous question.I have mentioned the previous question here also.

Comment: I think it's basically the same question, as is indicated by the 90% identical text. I think you should just update the other question.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Ok. I will update the question there.  One of the member here  suggest me to ask as  a new question. The solution of my  previous question is working perfectly without sorted transformation.That's y I thought of adding as a new question. Thanks