# difference in list of rows in the succeeding window from the preceeding window in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a *dataframe 1*. For each timeframe *'t'*, I want to compare the list of rows for two adjacent window of rows -- for example difference between ((a,b,c), (b,c,d)...) and ((a, b, c), (x, y, z)...) for t=1 and t=2 respectively. Basically, I want to get difference in list in the succeeding window from the preceeding window i.e. the *diff* operation between the two lists of lists in two time frames. The expected dataframe looks like a dataframe 2.

**Dataframe 1**

```
+---+---+---+---+
| t | A | B | C |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | a | b | c |   
| 1 | b | c | d |   
| 1 | c | d | e |   
| 1 | c | d | f |   
| 1 | d | e | f |   
| 2 | a | b | c |   
| 2 | x | y | z |   
| 2 | c | d | e |   
| 2 | w | x | y |   
| 3 | w | x | y |   
| 3 | c | d | e |   
| 3 | m | n | o |   
+---+---+---+---+
```

**Dataframe 2 (resultant dataframe)**

```
+---+------+
| t | Diff |
+---+------+
| 1 |  0   |
| 2 |  2   |   
| 3 |  1   |   
+---+------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: what you have tried so far? what is working and not working ?

Comment: I think these kind of problems (involving collection of rows for specific id) potentially have solutions with window+aggregation functions, but I haven't been able to resolve mine. I referred: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148208/how-do-i-compare-multiple-rows-of-a-table-using-spark-sql-data-frames-udf), [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148208/how-do-i-compare-multiple-rows-of-a-table-using-spark-sql-data-frames-udf), but couldn't relate to my problem